# Too many images on a screen causing the application to stutter

Tags: java, android, image

I got answers that solved my problems in this subject but this is something different.

When there's one image that falling from the screen (Animation from top to bottom)
The Application runs smoothly but when there's multiple (5~8) The apps stutters and lags.

I need to know why that problem occurs.

Here's the code :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                Rect rect = new Rect();
                                rocket.getHitRect(rect);

                                Rect rect1 = new Rect();
                                p1.getHitRect(rect1);

                                Rect rect2 = new Rect();
                                p2.getHitRect(rect2);

                                Rect rect3 = new Rect();
                                p3.getHitRect(rect3);

                                Rect rect4 = new Rect();
                                c1.getHitRect(rect4);

                                Rect rect5 = new Rect();
                                c2.getHitRect(rect5);

                                Rect rect6 = new Rect();
                                c3.getHitRect(rect6);
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect1)
                                        && p1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    if (!r1) {
                                        .....

                                    }
                                    r1 = true;

                                }
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect2)
                                        && p2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    if (!r2) {
                                        .....

                                    }
                                    r2 = true;

                                }
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect3)
                                        && p3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    if (!r3) {
                                        .....

                                    }
                                    r3 = true;

                                }
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect4)
                                        && c1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    if (!r4) {
                                        .....


                                    }
                                    r4 = true;

                                }
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect5)
                                        && c2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                                    if (!r5) {
                                        .....


                                    }
                                    r5 = true;

                                }
                                if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect6)
                                        && c3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    if (!r6) {
                                .....
                                    }
                                    r6 = true;

                                }
                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect1)) {
                                    r1 = false;
                                }

                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect2)) {
                                    r2 = false;
                                }

                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect3)) {
                                    r3 = false;
                                }

                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect4)) {
                                    r4 = false;
                                }

                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect5)) {
                                    r5 = false;
                                }

                                if (!Rect.intersects(rect, rect6)) {
                                    r6 = false;
                                }

                                downy1 += 1;
                                downy2 += 1;
                                downy3 += 1;
                                downy4 += 1;
                                downy5 += 1;
                                downy6 += 1;

                                params1.topMargin = params1.topMargin + downy1;
                                params2.topMargin = params2.topMargin + downy2;
                                params3.topMargin = params3.topMargin + downy3;
                                params4.topMargin = params4.topMargin + downy4;
                                params5.topMargin = params5.topMargin + downy5;
                                params6.topMargin = params6.topMargin + downy6;

                                p1.setLayoutParams(params1);
                                p2.setLayoutParams(params2);
                                p3.setLayoutParams(params3);
                                c1.setLayoutParams(params4);
                                c2.setLayoutParams(params5);
                                c3.setLayoutParams(params6);

                                if (p1.getTop() > height) {
                                    downy1 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params1.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params1.topMargin = orig1y;
                                    p1.setLayoutParams(params1);

                                }

                                if (p2.getTop() > height) {
                                    downy2 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params2.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params2.topMargin = orig2y;
                                    p2.setLayoutParams(params2);

                                }

                                if (p3.getTop() > height) {
                                    downy3 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params3.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params3.topMargin = orig3y;
                                    p3.setLayoutParams(params3);

                                }

                                if (c1.getTop() > height && !failedM) {
                                    downy4 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params4.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params4.topMargin = orig4y;
                                    c1.setLayoutParams(params4);
                                    c1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                                if (c2.getTop() > height && !failedM) {
                                    downy5 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params5.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params5.topMargin = orig5y;
                                    c2.setLayoutParams(params5);
                                    c2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }

                                if (c3.getTop() > height && !failedM) {
                                    downy6 = 0;
                                    int newX = new Random().nextInt(width - 1) + 1;
                                    params6.leftMargin = newX;
                                    params6.topMargin = orig6y;
                                    c3.setLayoutParams(params6);
                                    c3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }

                            }

                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 70);
```

You can see that the animation repeats it self every 60 milliseconds (Top to bottom then moving back to top and top to bottom).

Comment: The lack of infinite RAM and processing power is to blame, I suppose.

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Thanks for replying guys , What does it mean "plnkr"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timer for this operation.
Try to apply [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) and experiment with different interpolator.
Find in your IDE memory usage, you create many Rectangles. Try change this logic and operate with already created objects.

Comment: Thanks for relplying , Is it Below API 8 or exactly API 8?

Comment: Value animator has 11 api level. But, i think you problem in memory allocation. Discover your memory usage in DDMS or memory monitor.

Comment: What can I do to increase the memory ?

Comment: In android early android version nothing. Anyway, try to refactor you code. 
For example: Rect rect1 = new Rect(); - its wrong because in all steps of your code calling you crate object. Try to create global variable rect(for all rect's) and reuse it in timer.
EX:
public class YourClass { Rect rect, rect1 ....  
                         @Override
                            public void run() {
                           rect = new Rect(); .... }